# How could I pass token from cookies to each request using mobx?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, next.js, mobx-react

I'm writing a web application with Next.js and mobx.
How can I pass token (from cookies) for each request to API? Sometimes I should take it from the browser and sometimes from server side (context object).
Notice, that I make requests in mobx actions (@action).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you are calling the API. 
You can achieve that with Axios for example:

```
const token = localStorage.get('access_token');
const { data } = awit axios('/api/users', { headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${token}` } });
```

Comment: It's Next.js - server-side rendering. When it's server side, I don't have access to localstorage